# Trying to generate bokeh plots using python multiprocessing, ended up getting below error

Tags: python-3.x, serialization, pickle, bokeh, python-multiprocessing

I am trying to generate and return bokeh plots. In this process I am using python multiprocessing to speed up the process as I have more number of plots to generate.

Below is an example of how my code looks like ..

```
 from multiprocessing import Pool
 from bokeh.plotting import gridplot

 class A():
    def __init__(self, x, y, z):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.z = z

    def generate_bokeh_plot(self, id):
        # This method will generate and return bokeh plot
        # Also, I am using above x, y, z in this method 

        # This is an example of how my plot looks like and I am returning this
        plot = <class 'bokeh.plotting.figure.Figure'>

        return plot

obj = A(x,y,z)
# Mine is 8 core machine, I am using 7 at a time
pool = pool(7)
plots = pool.map(obj.generate_bokeh_plot, id_list)
pool.close()
pool.join()

panel = gridplot(plots)
script, div = components(panel)
```

For this I am getting the following error

```
multiprocess.pool.MaybeEncodingError: Error sending result: '[Column(id='b80aa557-5157-4d5d-b891-236642b96abe', ...)]'. Reason: 'PicklingError("Can't pickle <class 'bokeh.core.enums.Enumeration'>: it's not the same object as bokeh.core.enums.Enumeration",)'
```

I also tried using pathos, ended up getting same error

```
import pathos.pools as pp
p = pp.ProcessPool(7)
p.map()

or 

from pathos.multiprocessing import ProcessingPool as Pool
pool = Pool(7)
pool.map()
```

**My Environment:** I am using Python 3.6 with Pyramid web framework, RHEL

Any help on this issue will be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Yikes I have no idea what's going on here and honestly no idea if this will be workable or not. Bokeh has lots of automagic under the covers as well as its own serialization, I have no idea how that will interact with `multiprocessing`. Best suggesting is to farm out data computations (which I assume are actually what are compute intensive) an return results and assemble the plots/do all the Bokeh work (which should not take much computation) in the main process.